# Discord Message Spamming

Tags: discord.js

Hello I Made This Discord.js Code And Ms And Db And Idk Why But After The 20s It Starts Spamming Can You Tell Me How To Make It So Every 20s It Sends 1 Message

```js
const ms = require('ms')
client.on('message', tfcm => {
    if (tfcm.content.startsWith(prefix + 'setRoom')) {
        const room = tfcm.mentions.channels.first()
        if (!room) return tfcm.channel.send('⛔ | Please Put A Valid Channel')
        db.set(`room_${tfcm.guild.id}`, room.id)
        tfcm.channel.send(`✅ | Set ${room} As The Room For Things`)
    }
})


client.on('message', tfcm => {
    const roomid = db.fetch(`room_${tfcm.guild.id}`)
    if (!roomid) return
    const room = tfcm.guild.channels.cache.get(roomid)
    setTimeout(function() {
        room.send('test')
    }, ms('20s'))
})
```

Pls Help

Comment: Why do you have 2 message events?

Comment: Also, maybe try ignoring messages from bots. This way your client will ignore it's own message and prevent a message event loop

Answer (score -1):

There is two errors here first on message come event is duplicate and when you send message by setTimeout it not checking message by bot and continue to set another timeOut.

```js
const ms = require('ms')

client.on('message', tfcm => {

    if (tfcm.content.startsWith(prefix + 'setRoom')) {
        const room = tfcm.mentions.channels.first()
        if (!room) return tfcm.channel.send('⛔ | Please Put A Valid Channel')
        db.set(`room_${tfcm.guild.id}`, room.id)
        return tfcm.channel.send(`✅ | Set ${room} As The Room For Things`)
    }
    if(tfcm.author.bot) return; // Ignore BOT Message
    const roomid = db.fetch(`room_${tfcm.guild.id}`)
    if (!roomid) return
    const room = tfcm.guild.channels.cache.get(roomid)
    setTimeout(function() {
        room.send('test')
    }, ms('20s'))
})
```